# Android sdk 26 onwards- JNI GetObjectField called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError for custom array object

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

In **JNI**, I am calling a **custom array object**. I got its type from the foo.getclass().getName() and used that to get **GetFieldID**.
The type is like:   [L fully-qualified-class-name.

In **SDK 25**, I am able to get the '**GetObjectField**' without any error.

In **SDK 26**, I am getting the following error:

> A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION:
>   JNI GetObjectField called with pending exception
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no type "[Lcom..customClassName;"
>   found and so no field "fieldname" could be found in class
>   "Lcom..parentClass;" or its superclasses

I am aware that *there are some changes in the newer SDK*. But, I am not sure how to change it so that there is no error.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to **GetObjectArrayElement()** for the first element of the array and get its class with **GetObjectClass()**. Class names may be less reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about @Alex's comment as I was not able to try it.

I found this workaround though,

---

**Java Side:**

The custom object's class, **ClassA** has this class **ClassB**'s array object as below.

> public ClassB objb[] = new ClassB[size];

Now instead of sending just **ClassA**'s object to JNI, I sent the object of ClassA and **ClassB** separately. 
*As from JNI, it is not accepting custom object's type from SDK 26.*

> sendA(obja);
>
> sendB(obja.objb[0]);

---

**JNI Side:**

```
ClassA a;

 //sendA function for classA similiar as below.

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_<PATH_TO_FUNCTION>_sendB(JNIEnv *env,jobject instance,jobject BObj) {
    LOGD(TAG,"sendB: START");
    jclass jBClass=env->FindClass("com/< path to class separated by '/' >");

    //  int Field jbid

    jfieldID jbid = env->GetFieldID(jBClass, "bId", "I"); 
    jint bId = env->GetIntField(BObj, jbid);
    obja.objb[0].bId = (int) bId;
    LOGI(TAG, "\t bId[%d]: %d ", 0, obja.objb[0].bId); 
     return 0; 
   }
```

For **iterations**, you can use **for loop** at java side and send the iterator as a parameter of sendA() and sendB() to JNI.

---

Also, there is a way of **serializing** object into string and **deserializing** it back to object from JNI side.. But, being a novice in JNI, I was not confident enough to deserialize the custom array object on JNI side.